# How to prove- If $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ does not contain any of its limit point then $E$ is countable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $ E $ be a subset of $ \mathbb{R} $, the set of all real numbers. If $ E $ does not contain any of its limit points, then how can I prove that $ E $ is countable?

Thank you!

Comment: Since you are still new, I want to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $ E $ is uncountable. It suffices to show that $ E $ must contain a limit point. (Think of the contrapositive statement; $ A \to B $ is equivalent to $ \neg B \to \neg A $.)

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $ E $ does not contain any of its limit points. Then for every $ p \in E $, there exists a positive number $ \epsilon_{p} $ such that the interval $ (p - \epsilon_{p},p] $ is disjoint from $ E \setminus \{ p \} $.

> **Claim** $ \{ (p - \epsilon_{p},p] \}_{p \in E} $ is a collection of disjoint non-degenerate intervals of $ \mathbb{R} $.
>
> *Proof of the claim*: As $ \epsilon_{p} > 0 $, it is clear that $ (p - \epsilon_{p},p] $ is non-degenerate. Next, assume for the sake of contradiction that we have distinct $ p,q \in E $ such that $ (p - \epsilon_{p},p] \cap (q - \epsilon_{q},q] \neq \varnothing $. Without loss of generality, we may suppose that $ p < q $. However, this would imply that $ p \in (q - \epsilon_{q},q] $, which is a contradiction because $ (q - \epsilon_{q},q] \cap (E \setminus \{ q \}) = \varnothing $ by construction. The claim is thus established.

Now, by the claim, we see that $ \{ (p - \epsilon_{p},p] \}_{p \in E} $ is an uncountable collection of disjoint non-degenerate intervals, which is yet another contradiction. Therefore, our initial assumption that $ E $ does not contain any of its limit points is false.

**Conclusion** $ E $ must contain a limit point. Therefore, if $ E $ does not contain any limit point, it must be a countable set.

---

**Addendum**

As kindly pointed out by Jonas in his comments below, this result is true for a separable metric space (or pseudo-metric space). My choice of half-open intervals is applicable only to $ \mathbb{R} $, so for the general case, one can choose an $ \epsilon_{p} > 0 $ for every $ p \in E $ such that $ \mathbb{B}(p;\epsilon_{p}) \cap (E \setminus \{ p \}) = \varnothing $. Then $ \left\{ \mathbb{B} \left( p;\dfrac{1}{2} \epsilon_{p} \right) \right\}_{p \in E} $ is an uncountable collection of disjoint open balls, which would violate separability.

Comment: Serious question: do you think that proving the contrapositive of this statement is more illuminating?

Comment: I thought of using the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem like you did. However, the theorem only states that a bounded infinite set has a limit point and not that it *contains* a limit point. For example, the set $ \left\{ \dfrac{1}{n} \right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is infinite and bounded, but does not contain the limit point $ 0 $.

Comment: A ha, very good point. Thanks! (Also thanks to Matt E)

Comment: Direct proof outline: The set has no limit points, thus you can generate a disjoint collection of nondegenerate intervals each containing one element of the set. Note that there is an injection from this collection of intervals to the set of rational numbers, and the set of rational numbers is countable.

Comment: (A similar argument could be given in any separable metric space.  Instead of "half-open" intervals, one can choose $\varepsilon_p$ such that $B(p,\varepsilon_p)\cap E=\{p\}$, then consider the collection $\{B(p,\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_p):p\in E\}$.)

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Ah ha! Balls with half of the original radius are what I needed. I guess that I was too tired from trying to *calm the rhetoric* on another thread. Thanks for the comments, by the way!

Comment: Haskell: You're welcome.  I like your answer, and I hope you don't mind a mild criticism partly in response to @B.D's question.  While there are cases where contraposition is more illuminating, in this case the combination of contraposition and contradiction looks to me like a direct proof in disguise.

Comment: @Jonas: It's worse than that! The lemma is another proof by contradiction. So we have a proof by contradiction of the contradiction of the contrapositive. Haskell, I hope I never get into an argument with you...

Comment: @TonyK: Haha... I intend to incorporate all of your comments in a revised post soon. It has been a tiring day.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell Curry’s answer is more than sufficient, but I thought that it might be instructive to put it into a more general topological context.

More generally, let $X$ be a topological space. To say that $E\subseteq X$ does not contain any of its limit points is to say that $E$ is a discrete subset of $X$: each $x\in E$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap E=\{x\}$.

> **Definition:** The *spread* of $X$, denoted by $s(X)$, is the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $|D|\le\kappa$ for all discrete $D\subseteq X$. In other words, $$s(X)=\max\big\{\omega,\sup\{|D|:D\subseteq X\text{ is discrete}\}\big\}\;.$$

What you’ve been asked to prove is that $s(\Bbb R)=\omega$.

> **Definition:** A family $\mathscr{N}$ of subsets of $X$ is a *net* if for each open $U\subseteq X$ there is a family $\mathscr{N}_U\subseteq\mathscr{N}$ such that $U=\bigcup\mathscr{N}_U$. The *net weight* of $X$, denoted by $nw(X)$, is the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that $X$ has a net of cardinality $\kappa$. In other words, $$nw(X)=\max\big\{\omega,\min\{|\mathscr{N}|:\mathscr{N}\text{ is a net for }X\big\}\;.$$ The *weight* of $X$, denoted by $w(X)$, is defined similarly, but with *base* replacing *net*: $$w(X)=\max\big\{\omega,\min\{|\mathscr{N}|:\mathscr{N}\text{ is a base for }X\big\}\;.$$

Clearly any base of the topology of $X$ is a net, so $nw(X)\le w(X)$. In particular, we know that $\Bbb R$ is second countable, so $\omega\le nw(\Bbb R)\le w(\Bbb R)=\omega$, and therefore $nw(\Bbb R)=\omega$.

The point of all this is that it’s not hard to prove in general that $s(X)\le nw(X)$, from which we immediately get $s(\Bbb R)=\omega$, the desired result.

> **Proposition:** For any space $X$, $s(X)\le nw(X)$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $D$ be a discrete subset of $X$, and let $\mathscr{N}$ be a net for $X$ of cardinality $nw(X)$. Each $x\in D$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $U_x\cap D=\{x\}$. For each $x\in D$ there is an $\mathscr{N}_x\subseteq\mathscr{N}$ such that $U_x=\bigcup\mathscr{N}_x$, so there is an $N_x\in\mathscr{N}_x$ such that $x\in N_x\subseteq U_x$. Clearly $N_x\cap D=\{x\}$ for each $x\in D$, so the map $D\to\mathscr{N}:x\mapsto N_x$ is an injection, and $|D|\le|\mathscr{N}|=nw(X)$. $\dashv$

In fact even stronger statements are possible.

> **Definition:** The *density* of $X$, denoted by $d(X)$, is the smallest cardinality of a dense subset of $X$ (or $\omega$ if that is finite): $$d(X)=\max\big\{\omega,\min\{|D|:\operatorname{cl}D=X\}\big\}\;.$$ The *hereditary density* of $X$, denoted by $hd(X)$, is the supremum of the densities of subsets of $X$: $$hd(X)=\sup\{d(Y):Y\subseteq X\}\;.$$ The *Lindelöf degree* of $X$, denoted by $L(X)$, is the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that every open cover of $X$ has a subcover of cardinality at most $\kappa$. The *hereditary Lindelöf degree* of $X$, denoted by $hL(X)$, is defined similarly to the hereditary density: $$hL(X)=\sup\{L(Y):Y\subseteq X\}\;.$$

Thus, $X$ is separable iff $d(X)=\omega$, $X$ is hereditarily separable iff $hd(X)=\omega$, $X$ is Lindelöf iff $L(X)=\omega$, and $X$ is hereditarily Lindelöf iff $hL(X)=\omega$.

It’s very easy to show that $s(X)\le hd(X),hL(X)$ for any space $X$: if $D$ is a discrete subset of $X$, then $D$ itself is the only dense subset of $D$, and $\big\{\{x\}:x\in D\big\}$ is a relatively open cover of $D$ with no smaller subcover. Both of these inequalities are stronger than the inequality $s(X)\le nw(X)$, because $hd(X),hL(X)\le nw(X)$; I’ll leave that as an easy exercise.

In particular, $s(X)=\omega$ if $X$ is either hereditarily separable or hereditarily Lindelöf. There are hereditarily separable and hereditarily Lindelöf spaces that do not have countable net weight; perhaps the most familiar example is the [Sorgenfrey line $\Bbb S$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line), the real line topologized by taking $$\big\{[a,b):a,b\in\Bbb R\text{ and }a<b\big\}$$ as a base for the topology. Thus $\Bbb S$, like $\Bbb R$, has no uncountable discrete subset, though $\Bbb S^2$, **unlike** $\Bbb R^2$, does have one, namely, $\big\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x\in\Bbb S\big\}$.